# Need to save a copy of email using imap php and then can be open in outlook express

Tags: php, outlook, imap, express, eml

I had IMAP PHP script which is connecting and reading emails from the mail box.

What i am looking is that i want to save the email on server disk and name it something like testing.eml file. So when later i down those emails and can be viewed in outlook express. Any thoughts how can this be achieved.

Thanks,

Comment: $mbox = imap_open ("{localhost:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", "user_id", "password");

$file = '/your/file/eml/test.eml';

$f = fopen($file,'w+');

imap_savebody($mbox,$f,$messageNumber); // Here $messageNumber is a msg number u want to save

fclose($f);

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [PHP's IMAP reference](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php); here's the core functionality:

```
$mbox = imap_open ("{localhost:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", "user_id", "password");
$message_count = imap_num_msg($mbox);
if ($message_count > 0) {
    $headers = imap_fetchheader($mbox, $message_count, FT_PREFETCHTEXT);
    $body = imap_body($mbox, $message_count);
    file_put_contents('/your/file/here.eml', $headers . "\n" . $body);
}
imap_close($mbox);
```

What happens here:

- open the mailbox
- get message count
- if there are any:

  - get headers of the last one
  - get body of the last one
  - save them together in a file
- close the mailbox